# Parsing text file and collecting text into list object before outputting each list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, parsing

I'm working with a text file that has the following structure:

```
printer_name:
description = printer_description
library = printer_library
form = printer_form
```

This structure repeats for every printer in the database.

The desired output of the python script I'm working on would look like this:

```
'printer_name', 'printer_description', 'printer_library', 'printer_form'
'printer_name', 'printer_description', 'printer_library', 'printer_form'

...and so on for every printer record in the text file...
```

At this point, I keep running into problems with building the desired output while trying to collect each item into a list object for each record.

Here's the latest version I've been working with:

```
f = input('Enter file name:')
fh = open(f)

lst = list()
for line in fh:
    line = line.strip()
    if len(line) == 0: continue

    elif line.startswith('description'):
        descList = line.split()
        description = ' '.join(descList[2:])
        lst.append(description)

    elif line.startswith('library'):
        libList = line.split()
        libraryItem = libList[2:]
        library = libraryItem[0]
        lst = lst.append(library)

    elif line.startswith('form'):
        formList = line.split()
        formItem = (formList[2:])
        form = formItem[0]
        lst = lst.append(form)

    else:
        printer = line[:-1]
        lst = lst.insert(0, printer)

print(lst)
```

This script returns Python's attribute error indicating that 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'.  This appears to be referring to the lst.append(description) statement in my first elif block, however, when I comment out the remaining elif blocks and run the script that way, I am able to produce a single list of description items.

I'm thinking that in order to get a 'list' of lists on my way to getting the desired output, I'll need to situate the print(lst) statement so that it's called for every print record which has been built into its own line, but I've been having trouble with that aspect as well.

Anyone willing and able to take a stab at this puzzle for me?

I would really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

method `append` return `None`, so when you try `lst = lst.append(library)` set you variable to `None`
replace all:

```
lst = lst.append(library)
lst = lst.insert(0, printer)
```

to

```
lst.append(library)
lst.insert(0, printer)
```

if you need a `list` of `lines`
you can try the logic:

```
lines = list()
for line in fh:
    lst = list()
    # You code
    lines.append(lst)
```

Comment: That's great, thank you for pointing that out as I am now closer.  Still, the output is coming back as one large list.  I think at this point I could loop over this list skipping every four items [::4] and return each instance as a separate list and create a collection of lists from the existing large list.  Will work more on this...

Comment: glad to help you, don't forget to accept the answer, and read the update may be it help you

Comment: Thanks, what I have now appears to put every item into its own discrete list.  Still working towards that desired output goal which is to output each record in the db as a single line of delimited strings for every printer record in the db.